# Why does my list display with each object being "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]"

Tags: c#, .net, list

I want a list that starts five days before today and ends 10 days after today.
In the list I want to generate each day as a bullet point.

I seem to be getting the correct number of bullet points but each one has a value of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]

My Code is Below:

```
@{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    var end = start.AddDays(10);

    for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        <li>@dates</li>
        dates.Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]
```

I am sure whatever I am missing is obvious...and I feel stupid, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you want <li>@dt</li>.

Answer (score 3):

That's what you are telling it to do.

```
for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
   {
       <li>@dates</li> <-- for each iteration, print dates.tostring
       dates.Add(dt);
   }
```

The funcition `List<DateTime>.ToString()` just returns the typename, which in long form is `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.DateTime]`.

Try this code:

```
for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
   {
       <li>@dt</li> 
       dates.Add(dt);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, and just like I thought. I feel like a complete idiot. Thanks so much!

Comment: The important thing is you now know what to look for. Whenever you see what looks like class names in your output, you know that someone either (1) printed the wrong variable or (2) forgot to override `ToString()`.